# Webcam is only recognized by some software

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, flash, webcam

I have a webcam that works fine in software such as
[camorama](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/camorama/) and
[cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese). However, I cannot use it in
websites that allow you to use a webcam (it's not recognized).

I tested it with:

- Chromium 34.0 with Adobe Flash Player 11.2 (64 bits)
- Chromium 35.0 with [Pepper Flash
  Player](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer) **(32 bits)**
- Iceweasel 10.0 with Adobe Flash Player 11.2 (64 bits)

Update:

- Iceweasel 31.7.0 with HTML5 (appear.in) (64 bits)
- Chromium 43.0 with Pepper Flash

I also tried to use it with `avconv` and `pidgin`. Nothing.

As for the microphone, Chromium, some websites (such as appear.in) and Audacity recognize it. Other software such as avconv don't. In summary, it's a f*ing mess. And yes, I selected the same device and "sub device" both with Audacity and avconv and everywhere else. I use ALSA only, however I tried using PulseAudio too.

Websites don't seem to recognize the camera. Neither does
Chromium (all versions aforementioned):

[image]

Funny thing is, the mic it recognizes is **the webcam's microphone**!

I'm on Debian 7.6 (wheezy) (Update: 8.0 (jessie)), kernel is `x86_64 Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64` but I also tested on a 32 bits computer with the same system. The manufacturer's website says the webcam is supported on Linux. It's a cheap, national webcam (Satellite WB-537).

I also installed Windows XP on a VM and tried to get it working. Skype didn't
recognize it (but also recognized the camera's mic!). I downloaded ManyCam but
that didn't help.

PS: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191166/webcam-doesnt-work-in-browser)
is *not* the issue. I have the website I want under "allow" (without asking). It
just doesn't recognize the camera at all.

PPS: Buying a new webcam is an option, but since there's nothing wrong with the current one (as it works on camorama, etc), I'm not sure if it'd solve the issue.

I don't mind using whatever hack/kludge necessary to get it working.

Comment: Does your webcam work with websites that use html5, rather than flash, to access the camera?  Might be worth checking over at [Appear.in](https://appear.in) or Google Hangouts.  It's probably best to be 100% certain that it is flash causing the problem (not that I would ever doubt it).

Comment: @0xDAFACADE It only detects the mic on the camera. I assume it's because, as I mentioned, Chromium itself seems to fail detecting the camera. Nice website btw. PS: I edited the title to not give the idea flash is the issue.

Comment: I have same issue https://superuser.com/questions/1290361/webcam-detection-in-chromium-on-fresh-ubuntu-install . Did you find a way around ?

Answer (score -1):

Is chromium installed as a snap ?
If yes, you have to connect the system core camera to the snap one, this is done by:

```
$ sudo snap connect chromium:camera :camera
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted, it looks like a sensible piece of advice.